# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

In my process to change password of MySQL server, I had to run this line on command

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql root -p

Which later showed error something like

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Please help me out with this one guys.

Answer (score 4):

you need simply typing

```
mysql
```

without specifying a username will attempt to connect with the non-existent ODBC username, and give:

**Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

instead, try specifying a username that you know, for example:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

where `-u root` specified the username `root` and `-p` will make the command prompt for a password.

Comment: It's sad to say this but, I got this with that:


C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ************
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: you need to go bin folder and rund mysqld service, closing cmd and run mysql.exe

Answer (score 0):

try with -u parameter,

```
mysql -u root -p
```

after typing this command the prompt will ask for the password of the respective user.

That's it